# How to keep thread alive throughout the windows application c#

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

I am using thread which will receive messages from the 
external application.So my thread shud be alive always.

I want my thread to be running through out the application, 
untill application exits. Currently i am calling my thread in program.cs, 
which is the startup for windows application c#. Please see the code below 
to know how i am doing it.

When i use the below code, the thread starts up when 
application starts...But it aborts some how, after the thread recieves
 one message from the external application.

I hope i am clear with my questio. Please help. Thanks.

---

```
  static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        StartThread();
        Application.Run(new Screensaver());
    }
    public static void StartThread()
    {
            DeamonEngine Deamon = new DeamonEngine();
            Thread ThreadReciever = new Thread(Deamon.Receiver);
            if (!(ThreadReciever.IsAlive))
            {
                ThreadReciever.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

From a comment:

```
    void Receiver() { 
        try { 
            Initiate socket s; 
            Bind Ip address; 
            s.Receiver[bytes]; 
            Access the members of message received in bytes;
            Assign the members of message to local variable;
            Read Xml File, get the node values and write to batch file; 
            Execute batch file. 
        } 
        catch { } 
    }
```

Comment: Karthik, several times you said there's a loop. Could you please show us the loop? I don't see one. The code you posted will execute once, then the thread will terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a thread execute the Receiver method doesn't mean the thread will repeatedly execute the method.

Given the processing code in the question, `Daemon.Receiver` needs to execute in a loop so that it can go back and retrieve the next message to process.  It should look something like this:

```
void Receiver() { 
    while(!done) // without this loop, only one execution will occur
    {
        try { 
            // do stuff
        } 
        catch { 
            // log/handle error
        } 

        // wait for next message
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. My Deamon.receiver method picks up the message. Its running a loop for processing the message i get. But once it process the first message, it aborts.

Comment: can you put a quick outline of the Deamon.Receiver method up?  without the main logic of course... just leave in the looping statements, and the try catches, etc...

Comment: Receiver()
{
  try {
   Initiate socket s;
   Bind Ip address;
   s.Receiver[bytes];
   Access the members of message received in bytes.
   Assign the members of message to local variable.
   Read Xml File, get the node values and write to batch file.
   Execute batch file.
 }
 catch
  {
   }
}

Comment: it'd be useful to add that to the question so everyone can see it.
where's the loop part?

Answer (score 2):

Your startup code looks fine: my prognosis is there's something wrong with `DaemonEngine.Receiver()`, perhaps an exception is being thrown, or perhaps the function itself is structured to only handle a single message... Without seeing the exact function it's hard to say.

**EDIT:**

To get my stuff out of my comments:

SOMETHING is going wrong to kill your thread. Exception, logical error, I can't tell you what, because there's no code of what's happening inside your thread, but something is happening. It's nothing to do with the code you've posted already which simply gets the thread running, not keeps it running

Also, from the code you have posted, you're simply throwing away the fact there was an exception... I don't have a link on hand, but swallowing exceptions like that is *horrible*. Especially inside a thread where they don't show up like normal anyway.

There's also no indication of a loop of any kind, so it could be one or both of my suggestions above that is causing problems.

Comment: My Deamon.receiver method picks up the message without any exception. I am shure of that, becuase the processing of first message is working fine and i also debugged line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Typically your DaemonReceiver would have code like this

```
while (!quit) 
{
  --- do work ---
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

This keeps the thread alive until you set the `quit` global variable in the main thread.

Also, it is very important to not let exceptions leak out of your thread. These exceptions will not be reported anywhere and will cause silent errors, probably what you're experiencing now. Do a catch all and at least report on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread might be experiencing a Exception, which is not being caught.  Try putting a try-catch in the method that is being executed and see if you're getting an exception.

Comment: My Deamon.receiver method picks up the message without any exception. I am shure of that, becuase the processing of first message is working fine and i also debugged line by line.